# Maximum occurrence of any set of words in text in R

Tags: r, string, text-mining

Given a set of lines, I have to find maximum occurrence of words(need not be single word, can be set of words also.)

say, I have a text like,

```
string <- "He is john beck. john beck is working as an chemical engineer. Most of the chemical engineers are john beck's friend"
```

I want output to be,

```
john beck - 3
chemical engineer - 2
```

Is there any function or package which does this?

Comment: This might combine words which are not nearby also. I want words which occur together. And also, that need not be two words, any number of words which occur together in many places, then I want to find the set of words and their count also.

Comment: As I mentioned, words occuring together is difficult to distinguish. For example `He is` occur together, so as `is john`, so it is not specific

Comment: Sounds like you might need to wrap some logic around the `ngram` package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ngram/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string <- "He is john beck. john beck is working as an chemical engineer. Most of the chemical engineers are john beck's friend"
library(tau)
library(tm)
tokens <- MC_tokenizer(string) 
tokens <- tokens[tokens != ""]
string_ <- paste(stemCompletion(stemDocument(tokens), tokens), collapse = " ")

## if you want only bi-grams: 
tab <- sort(textcnt(string_, method = "string", n = 2), decreasing = TRUE)
data.frame(Freq = tab[tab > 1])
#                   Freq
# john beck            3
# chemical engineer    2

## if you want uni-, bi- and tri-grams: 
nmin <- 1; nmax <- 3
tab <- sort(do.call(c, lapply(nmin:nmax, function(x) textcnt(string_, method = "string", n = x) )), decreasing = TRUE)
data.frame(Freq = tab[tab > 1])
#                   Freq
# beck                 3
# john                 3
# john beck            3
# chemical             2
# engineer             2
# is                   2
# chemical engineer    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also try this, using the [quanteda](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda) package:

```
require(quanteda)
mydfm <- dfm(string, ngrams = 1:2, concatenator = "_", stem = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
topfeatures(mydfm)
##           beck           john      john_beck         chemic chemical_engin          engin             is 
##              3              3              3              2              2              2              2 
##             an        an_chem            are 
##              1              1              1
```

You lose the stems, but this counts "john beck" three times instead of just two (since without stemming, "john beck's" will be a separate type).

It's simpler though!